# Applying a coupon code to an existing order - (without cancelling)

Tags: orders, coupon

I have a customer that has ordered a product that isn't ready to ship. To compensate the customer, I'd like to offer a discount by applying a coupon code on their pending order.

I'm aware that I can cancel the order and then apply the discount, but since this is a credit card transaction, I do not want to cancel the order or obligate the customer to "checkout" for a second time.

How can a discount be applied to an existing order ? (without cancelling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no inbuilt functionality for this that I know of. I would suggest to simply create a credit memo that contains no items but instead uses an Adjustment Refund. Depending on your payment method this might already automatically refund the money back to the customer.